# How do I create a new file with text outputted from a command?

Tags: unix, terminal, cat

I just want to create a file with the outputted text from a command, rather then copying and pasting & making a new file by hand.

I'm on a unix machine - how do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Redirecting. At the end of any command, type `> filename.txt`. Replace `filename.txt` with the file name you want to use. You can even output to different devices (dangerous) or directories (`ls > /home/user/ls.txt` for example)

As @Josh pointed out as well:

> If you need to see the output too you can use the `tee` command to output to stdout as well as a file. `ls | tee file.txt`

Comment: If you need to see the output too you can use the tee command to output to stdout as well as a file. ls | tee file.txt

Comment: Plus to append an existing file, use >>.